# md-virtual-repeat by given number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have some number that coming from database and I want to repeat some list over this number. Lets say `366` comes from database it has to repeat 366 times.

Below code is working but angular material's `md-virtual-repeat` does not support `track by` attribute. Is what I want achiveable?

```
$scope.number = 5; //Coming from database

$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
return new Array(num);   
}

<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">{{$index+1}}</li>
```

Comment: why dont you use the same code on material too?

Comment: @Sajeetharan `md-virtual-repeat does` not support `track by` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zKQWxG)

This is taken from the Vertical Usage example from the [demo page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat).

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" class="virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout="column">
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
      <li md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.items" class="repeated-item" flex="">
        {{$index + 1}}
      </li>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

    angular
      .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function() {
        this.items = new Array(366);        
      });
})();
```